# How can I import a csv skipping rows if there is a certain value in one column?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Python n00b, here. I'm working with event data in csv files. I am writing a script that changes the order of the columns, and sorts by time. That part of the script works, but I want to filter out certain rows based on the value of one column:

```
Description   Date     Start End   Location         Organization
Meeting       2/14/14  9:00  9:30  Conference Room  Org1
Meeting       2/14/14  9:30  10:00 Conference Room  Org2
```

If I don't want Org1, how do I filter out rows for that group's meetings.

I am using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('day_of_the_week.csv')
df = df.sort('MEETING START TIME')
#saved_column = df.column_name #you can also use df['column_name']
location = df.LOCATION
date = df.DATE
starttime = df['MEETING START TIME']
endtime = df['MEETING END TIME']
description = df.DESCRIPTION
organization = df.ORGANIZATION

#write new csv file with new order of columns
df.to_csv('Full_List_sorted.csv', cols=["DATE","MEETING START TIME","MEETING END TIME","DESCRIPTION","ORGANIZATION","LOCATION"],index=False)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter out those rows from df, do the following:

```
df = df[df["Organization"]!="Org1"]
```

Also, if it helps (I also started using Pandas just this week), there's a very quick and nice tutorial here:

http://manishamde.github.io/blog/2013/03/07/pandas-and-python-top-10/
(that's not me!)

Comment: Thanks Falcon9! That did it. And thanks for the tutorial, I'll definitely need it.

Answer (score 0):

Read It all. Then Create a new dataframe using pandas search. Finally store the new frame